# Having issue implementing "user is typing" feature for react.js + socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to display "user is typing" message by calling `handleTyping` function when input field changes. When user stops typing for more than 3 seconds, remove the "user is typing" message. I try to clear the previous timer at the beginning of the function call, but somehow "test" still gets printed in console N times when I type in N letters. This is causing the "user is typing" message to flicker after first 3 seconds, what can I do to "refresh" the timer on each key press so that `isTyping` state is always true unless 3 seconds of inactivity?

client side code:

```
const handleTyping = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    setCurrentMessage(e.target.value);

    if (!isTyping) socket.current.emit("typing", room);

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("test");
      socket.current.emit("stopTyping", room);
    }, 3000);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to build this on the client side. As long as the producer is typing, the state "typing" is emitted.

On the client side you can build a timer function. As soon as the "typing" message is received you set a "user is typing" text and reset the timer.
As soon as the timer resets, you'll remove the "user is typing" message.

```
// option 1 on producer side  (every key stroke)

const handleTyping = (e) => {
   socket.current.emit("typing", room);  // this will overload the socket server, if users are typing fast.
}

// option 2 on producer side (Only send "typing" every 500ms to the socket server, to prevent overloading)

let timer; // This var must be outside of the handleTyping function
const handleTyping = (e) => {
    if (timer === null) {
        socket.current.emit("typing", room);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            timer = null;
        }, 500);
    }
}

// client side

let timer;

socket.on("typing", () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    setTypingText("user is typing")
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setTypingText("");
    }, 3000);
});
```

NOTE: If the producer and the client are the same application, use a different variable name for `timer` if they are in the same "scope". Otherwise they will conflict with eachother.